# Can I enforce query parameter order in OpenApi?

Tags: http, openapi, cdn

The reason is for CDN cache entries. Those are specific strings used as cache keys and to invalidate them they need to match. Preferably, I'd like to enforce the query param order so that they always will match the CDN cache keys.

Comment: It respects the order with OpenAPI v3 and Spring Boot. Which framework/language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to just enforce ordering when building the query string.

Comment: how Openapi order of requestparam?